# Get part of URL with PHP

Tags: php, url

I have a site and I would need to get one pages URL with PHP. The URL might be something `www.mydomain.com/thestringineed/` or it can `www.mydomain.com/thestringineed?data=1` or it can be `www.mydomain.com/ss/thestringineed`

So it's always the last string but I dont want to get anything after ?

Comment: I can not understand, you want to get `www.mydomain.com` or `thestringineed/` ?

Comment: To clarify, from `/ss/thestringineed` you _only_ want `thestringineed` right?

Comment: Yes thestringineed is the only part i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use the parse_url function, then look at the path portion of the return. 
like this:

```
$url='www.mydomain.com/thestringineed?data=1';
$components=parse_url($url);

//$mystring= end(explode('/',$components['path']));

// I realized after this answer had sat here for about 3 years that there was 
//a mistake in the above line
// It would only give the last directory, so if there were extra directories in the path, it would fail. Here's the solution:
$mystring=str_replace( reset(explode('/',$components['path'])),'',$components['path']); //This is to remove the domain from the beginning of the path.

// In my testing, I found that if the scheme (http://, https://, ...) is present, the path does not include 
//the domain. (it's available on it's own as ['host']) In that case it's just  
// $mystring=$components['path']);
```

Comment: I'd have to test it, but you might have to `rtrim($components['path'],'/') 
` in case it ends in a slash. My posted answer might return a null string in that case.

Answer (score 4):

`parse_url` should help you out.

```
<?php
   $url = "http://www.mydomain.com/thestringineed/";
   $parts = parse_url($url);

   print_r($parts);
?>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.  In the case of `/ss/thestringineed`, it will return the whole thing, not just `thestringineed` in the path portion.

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is the function you are looking for.  The exact part you want, can be received through `PHP_URL_PATH`

```
$url = 'http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php';
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` it will return full current page url you can split it with '/' and use the last array index . it will be the last string

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$strings = explode("/", $urlstring);
```

Which will remove all the '/' in the url and return an array containing all the words.

```
$strings[count($strings)-1]
```

Now has the value of the string you need, but it may contain '?data=1' so we need to remove that:

```
$strings2 = explode("?", $strings[count($strings)-1]);

$strings2[0]
```

Has the string you are wanting out of the url.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

and your out put is

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```