# How to extract a specific area from a user submitted URL in PHP

Tags: php

This may be easy to do but I'm trying to extract only the highlighted area of the url a user will enter into a field. It will always be between the end `/` and `?`

**Note:**

To clarify, this is just a simple text input field that is pasted. I don't need to modify the page url.

**USER FIELD URL**

```
<?php $url = 'https://example.com/test/5tPa414MNG1cNfGjJs1Jr?si=tKTd7qJQ1Sda1ZUWoA5Q'; ?>
```

**WHAT I NEED TO EXTRACT**

https://example.com/test/`5tPa414MNG1cNfGjJs1Jr`?si=tKTd7qJQ1Sda1ZUWoA5Q

The code block section only.

**END RESULT**

```
<?php $extracted = '5tPa414MNG1cNfGjJs1Jr'; ?>
```

Comment: read about .htaccess and look to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064833/how-to-write-htaccess-file-to-get-everything-after-slash-as-parameter

Comment: Hi @Matt, updated my question. I don't need to update the page URL, this is just a field that a user will paste the URL into and save on the database.

Comment: Get last part of url in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448887/get-part-of-url-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions as said in an other answer, but they consume performances and aren't mandatory in this case.
Here, I'm splitting the URL on the '/' character, and I take the last part. Then I pick a substring from the beginning of the last part to the '?'.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://example.com/test/5tPa414MNG1cNfGjJs1Jr?si=tKTd7qJQ1Sda1ZUWoA5Q';
//Explode the URL on the /
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
//Get the last part
$lastItem = end($urlParts);
$extracted = substr($lastItem, 0, strpos($lastItem, '?'));
```

This solution gives the same result as the others, but it doesn't use regular expression.

Comment: That's great, I will go with this method instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've added some explanation about what I've done in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
preg_match("/(?<=\/)(\w+)(?=\?)/", $url, $match);
echo $match[0];
```